# Expose kubernetes deployment on master's IP

Tags: kubernetes

I have simple deployment which has 3 replicas. I want this deployment to be load balanced between this 3 replicas, but available under IP of my `master` and on some specified port.

This cluster was created by using `kubeadm`, I have one master and 20 worker nodes.

- I tried to expose the service as `LoadBalancer`, but this only works when you have cloud load balancer configured. I don't have such thing and `EXTERNAL-IP` is always `<pending>`.
- I tried to expose the service as `NodePort`, but this only works on nodes where `pods` were created. So for example after rollout, when `pods` will be created on different nodes, it will stop working. Also I guess this is not load balanced properly.
- I tried to create `ingress` to make it work, but unsuccessfully.

  ```
  apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    name: registry-ingress
    namespace: registry
    annotations:
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  spec:
    rules:
    - http:
      paths:
        - path: /registry
          backend:
            serviceName: registry-service
            servicePort: 5000
  ```

What is the proper approach here?

---

If the above is possible then second question: is it possible to expose it on 2 masters if I will want to create 2nd one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wrong about the `NodePort` approach. It was firewall blocking the connection to my master on ports `30000-32767`.

After unblocking this ports everything was working fine with `NodePort` service.